# Solving a vector equation

Tags: equation-solving, core-language

I want a simple and intuitive way of solving for $t$ given that $\mathbf{i},\, \mathbf{j},\, \mathbf{k}$ are the unit vectors in $\mathbf{R}^3$.
$$
5 = (2 \mathbf{i} - 3 \mathbf{k} + (\mathbf{i} - \mathbf{j} + \mathbf{k})\, t)\cdot(2 \mathbf{i} + 3 \mathbf{j} + 4 \mathbf{k})
$$
I want to point out that I often get equations provided like this and I am not looking to solve it. I do understand that $(4-12+t\,(2-3-4))=5$ provides me with the answer 13/5. Now I am simply interested in solving this with as little as possible transformation of the expressions.

Comment: a quick simple and intuitive way would do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
i = {1, 0, 0}; 
j = {0, 1, 0};
k = {0, 0, 1}; 
    Solve[5 == (2 i - 3 k + (i - j + k) t).(2 i + 3 j + 4 k), t]
```

(*
{{t -> 13/3}}
*)

Comment: How does mathematica know to match terms when using the dot. I thought that it was the case that i needed to use {} to be able to use the dot product

Comment: *Mathematica* substitutes the (list) values for $i$, $j$, and $k$ when executing `Solve`.

Comment: One could also do `{i, j, k} = IdentityMatrix[3];`, or use `UnitVector[]`…

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. That's what I did in the answer of which this is a duplicate...